# Unexpected NameError occurs when trying to use a dataframe name defined within a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Could somebody explain why the following code produces a `NameError`?

```
def nonull(df, col, name):
    name = df[pd.notnull(df[col])]
    print name[col].count(), df[col].count()
    return name

nonull(sve, 'DOC_mg/L', 'sveDOC')
sveDOC.count()

NameError: name 'sveDOC' is not defined

711 711
```

The `dataframe` seems to be created as the `print` statement works, so I don't understand why when I try to use `sveDOC` (which was `name` inside the function) it produces an error.

Here's an example of what I'd like to do within the function:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'one' : pd.Series([1., 1., 1., 1.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']), 
     'two' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}
pd.DataFrame(d)
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df1 = df
df = df * 2
print df.head(), df1.head()

one  two
a    2    2
b    2    4
c    2    6
d    2    8    
one  two
a    1    1
b    1    2
c    1    3
d    1    4
```

Comment: Where is it you expect this code defines the name `sveDOC`?!

Comment: Why you overriding the name variable inside function? `name = df`

Comment: You pass in `name` to your function, then immediately assign `df` to `name`. Why do you do that? Then it completely ignores whatever `name` was and overwrites it.

Comment: I had that `name = df` line to make it easier for me to read (I've removed it now). `sve`/ (the df argument) is a `DataFrame` so I thought I was making a `DataFrame` called `sveDOC`/(name argument) which is returned at the end of the function. Within the function the `name` works (on the `print` line) so I don't understand why I doesn't work after returning the result of the function.

Comment: @Cyber @Aamir Adman I wanted to have a copy of the original `DataFrame` so that I could alter the copy without effecting the original. I've added some example code that will run to demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: Even with copy this code still doesn't work. This makes for a confusing question.

Comment: @AndyHayden You're right I restarted my kernal and it no longer works so I guess the values had been stored when I was experimenting outside of a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python names *do not* work the way you seem to think. Here's what your code actually does:

```
def nonull(df, col, name):
    name = df # rebind the name 'name' to the object referenced by 'df'
    name = df[pd.notnull(name[col])] # rebind the name 'name' again 
    print name[col].count(), df[col].count()
    return name # return the instance

nonull(sve, 'DOC_mg/L', 'sveDOC') # call the function and ignore the return value
```

The function never actually uses the `'sveDOC'` argument. Here's what you should actually do:

```
def nonull(df, col):
    name = df[pd.notnull(df[col])]
    print name[col].count(), df[col].count()
    return name

sveDOC = nonull(sve, 'DOC_mg/L')
sveDOC.count()
```

---

Your conception of Python's use of names and references is completely wrong.

```
pd.DataFrame(d) # creates a new DataFrame but doesn't do anything with it
                # (what was the point of this line?)
df = pd.DataFrame(d) # assigns a second new DataFrame to the name 'df'
df1 = df # assigns the name `df1` to the same object that 'df' refers to
         # - note that this does *not* create a copy
df = df * 2 # create a new DataFrame based on the one referenced by 'df' 
            # (and 'df1'!)and assign to the name 'df'
```

To demonstrate this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)

df2 = df1

df1 is df2
Out[5]: True # still the same object

df2 = df2 * 2

df1 is df2
Out[7]: False # now different
```

If you want to create a copy of a `DataFrame`, do so explicitly:

```
df2 = copy(df1)
```

You can either do this outside `nonull` and pass the copy, or do it inside `nonull` and `return` the modified copy.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, originally I had code assigning `sveDOC` to a new `DataFrame` outside of a function `sveDOC = sve[pd.notnull(sve[col])]` but as I needed do this I number of time I wanted to have the process as part of a function. Is the a way to set a `DataFrame` to a new name within a function?

Comment: @Bprodz it's not clear what you're asking. Names in Python are just references to objects; it makes no sense to try to "rename" a variable.

Comment: I've added some more code to the bottom of my question and the output it produces to show what I mean as I think I'm using the terms incorrectly.
In the code I make a `DataFrame` and then assign it to another name, this allows me to make changes to the first or second `DataFrame` without independently (after multiplying the original `DataFrame` by 2 its copy remains unchanged)
I'd like to do the same thing, but in a function. I want to do this so that the original `DataFrame` is left unchanged.

Comment: @Bprodz I have added more to my answer - the fact that `df1` wasn't the same object as `df` was more-or-less a coincidence.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain how names and reference work, you're right- my understanding was completely wrong and but I my code had been working until but not the reason I thought it was.

So, do I understand your last comment in your code correctly that in some cases the `=` sign will causing a new `DataFrame` object to be created?

Comment: @Bprodz no, the `=` is just assignment - it's the `*` that calls `DataFrame.__mul__`, which returns a separate object.

Comment: Okay thanks, I ended up using `.copy()` in the function from `pandas` instead as it returns a `DataFrame` object.

Comment: @Bprodz there's a subtle thing here that = can create a copy if used along with loc/iloc/ix.